# Java.SQL Error: Prepared Statement not in batch mode

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I am using Java with backend HSQL. My prepared statement was working fine earlier. Recently, I created dependencies between department and items table and made the dep_seq_id column from auto generated seq_id to a simple column(we are updating id through java code now). After these changes, all dependent table create/update are failing with error like 
"statement not in batch mode".

The tables structure are like this:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT
  (
    DEP_SEQ_ID  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DEPT_STATE  VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    NAME        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    YEAR        VARCHAR(4),
    CREATE_DATE DATE,
    LINK        VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(SEQ_ID,DEPT_STATE)
  );

CREATE TABLE ITEMS
  (
    ITEM_ID    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ITEM_STATE VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    NAME       VARCHAR(20),
    ITEM_CODE  VARCHAR(10),
    DEP_SEQ_ID INTEGER,
    DEPT_STATE VARCHAR(6),
    FOREIGN KEY(DEP_SEQ_ID,DEPT_STATE) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(SEQ_ID, DEPT_STATE) ON
  DELETE CASCADE ON
  UPDATE CASCADE
  );
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrong here. Following is the code where I am trying to insert data in Items table, partial code is shown below.     I hope it makes sense, I have changed names and columns, as I cant share the actual code.

```
 PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet generatedKeys = null;
    Long mappingId = null;

    try {
        statement = m_connection.prepareStatement("insert into ITEMS (ITEM_ID, ITEM_STATE, NAME, ITEM_CODE, DEP_SEQ_ID, DEPT_STATE) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        for(WersMapping wersMapping : wersMapList){

        statement.setLong(1, item.getItemId());
        statement.setInt(2, item.getState());
        statement.setString(3, item.getName());
        statement.setString(4, item.getItemCode());

        statement.setInt(5, item.getDeptId());
        statement.setString(6, item.getDeptState());
        statement.addBatch();
        }

    int[] nArray = statement.executeBatch();
    int totalInserts = 0;
    if(nArray != null){

        for(int n:nArray){
            totalInserts = totalInserts + n;
        }
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Successfully created "+totalInserts + " Mapping instances");
    }
    return new Long(totalInserts) ;
```

**Error Stack:**

```
Aug 17, 2015 3:42:33 PM ItemMapDao create
SEVERE: Error inserting into Items Mapping table
java.sql.SQLException: statement is not in batch mode
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlExceptionSQL(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
        at com.ItemMapDao.create(ItemMapDao.java:367)
        at access.MaintanenceDac.updateFeatureSpecificData(MaintanenceDac.java:907)
        at access.MaintanenceDac.updateFeatureState(MaintanenceDac.java:649)
        at access.MaintanenceDac.updateCell(MaintanenceDac.java:154)
        at services.MaintainServices.updateSystemFeature(MaintainServices.java:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:183)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:48)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:119)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: statement is not in batch mode
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        ... 88 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 int affectedRows = statement.executeBatch();
```

The return type of `executeBatch()` is int[].

Try changing this.

Comment: I could not copy paste the code, so made a mistake there. Please ignore if you see any syntax error. The code compiles fine.I am facing runtime error.

Comment: Can you check if the batch is empty ? This exception is also caused when the batch is empty i.e. there are no items in the batch. check at : `for(WersMapping wersMapping : wersMapList){`

Comment: Thanks @Maverick, I noticed that there is some data issue in my local, hence the batch itself was empty.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [executeBatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()) instead of `executeUpdate`.

Also make sure that your code calls `addBatch` at least one. See http://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/discussion/73673/thread/926b13f4/

Comment: sorry I wrote, excuteUpdate by mistake, in my code, it is using executeBatch. Corrected in the question as well.

Comment: Can you post full stack trace of the error you are getting?

Comment: added in the question

Comment: As @Maverick mentioned in another comment most likely `addBatch` has been never called. See http://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/discussion/73673/thread/926b13f4/

Comment: Thanks for adding the link.